# bash output redirection limits?

Tags: bash, redirect, output, limits

I try to concatenate large files (some GB) in bash. I tried

```
    cat file1 file2 file3 > result
```

and it didn't work while

```
    cat file1 file2 file3 >> result
```

worked. In both occasions the file result didn't exist before and my expectation would be, that both commands give the same result.

On the same system I tried the same thing with small files (just some bytes) and both commands produce the same output. I tried to find some explanation (for example [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)) but couldn't find any...

So, I know how to solve my problem, but I'm still puzzled. Is anyone able to produce a clue?

Comment: What happened when you run the first command?

Comment: Are those files all _regular files_?

Comment: @lcd047 the individual files are .gz.parts and the result would not let me decompress it it gave an error

Comment: @Alepac yes no devices or anything virtual, just normal files

Comment: Are you using this command to write a conatenate file or you redirect through a pipe `|` to gunzip?

Comment: @Alepac I tried playing with pipes and combining commands but when it didn't work I ended up creating a new concatenated file without any pipes, just the command as displayed above

Comment: What's the error that you have trying to write to file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83330/discussion-between-silentfury-and-alepac).

Comment: Which filesystem are you on? How big is each file?

Answer (score 1):

when I need to split file I use a trick that works very well:

```
tar --one-file-system -czv /home | split -b 4000m - /media/DRIVENAME/BACKUPNAME.tgz
```

then, to restore :

`cat /media/DRIVENAME/BACKUPNAME.tgz.* | tar -x /`

so cat do the job whatever the containt is. So if it doesn't work whether there is a bad production of your splited files, or a limitation with your filesystem. What filesystem are you using ?